# strcpy(char*,char a[]) is giving incorrect output. (Reversing a string word by word)

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, reverse

What I'm trying to achieve -

**Input**: (String literal assumed.) `This is a string`

**Output**: `string a is This`

**My naive solution:**

1. Copy the string literal to an char array.
   Current contents of the char array str[sizeofstring] : `This is a string`
2. Reverse the array word by word and store it in another array.
   char reverse[sizeofstring]: `sihT si a gnirts`
3. Traverse array reverse from the last to the 0th position. Store it in char array solution.
   char solution[sizeofstring]: `string a is This`
4. `strcpy(pointertoachar, solution)`. - Because the function needs to return a pointer to char.

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *reverse(char *input) {
    int n = strlen(input);
    char str[n];

    char reverse[n];
    char solution[n];

    char *solutionp = malloc(sizeof(char) * n);
    strcpy(str, input);

    int last = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int q = 0;

    while (str[i] != '\0') {
        if (str[i] == ' ') {
            printf("i : %d\n", i);
            printf("LAST:%d\n", last);
            for (int t = (i - 1); t >= last; t--) { 
                reverse[q] = str[t];
                q++;
            }
            last = i + 1;
            reverse[q] = ' ';
            q++;
        }
        i++;
    }

    // for the last word.
    for (int cc = i - 1; cc >= last; cc--) {
        reverse[q] = str[cc];
        q++;
    }

    // Traversing from the last index to the first.
    int ii;
    int bb = 0;
    for (ii = n - 1; ii >= 0; ii--) {
        solution[bb] = reverse[ii];
        bb++;
    }

    // This prints the right output.
    // printf("%s\n",solution);

    // Copying from a char array to pointer pointing to a char array.
    strcpy(solutionp, solution);

    return solutionp;
}

int main() {
    char *str = "This is a string";
    char *answer;

    answer = reverse(str);
    printf("%s\n", answer);

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**The problem:**

Steps 1 to 3 are working as intended. For debugging purpose, I tried printing the output of the array which contains the solution and it worked, but when I copy it to char array pointed by a pointer using `strcpy` and return the pointer, it prints garbage values along with partially right output.

> **OUTPUT:** 
>   string a is This??Z??

There seems to be some problem in step 4. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `int n = strlen(input);
    char str[n];[...]strcpy(str,input);` out-of-bounds write, undefined behavior.

Comment: Remember that strings must have room for the NUL termination character. Your str variable is one byte short.

Comment: @BjornA. I tried changing str[n],reverse[n], solution[n] to [n+1] respectively. Still outputs the same.

Comment: @EOF What else could I do here? because I wouldn't know the size of the string literal.

Comment: Are you aware of the function named strrchr()? It can be used to find word separators, and memcpy() can be used to copy the different words.

Comment: @BjornA. I'm fairly new to c, will check that option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The major problem in your code is you allocate your temporary buffers one byte too short. You must make enough room for the final `'\0'` byte at the end of the strings.

You can simplify the code by using an auxiliary function to copy a block in reverse order:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *reverse_block(char *dest, const char *src, int len) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        dest[i] = src[len - i - 1];
    }
    dest[len] = '\0';
    return dest;
}

char *reverse_words(const char *string) {
    int i, last;
    int len = strlen(string);
    char temp[len + 1];

    for (i = last = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (string[i] == ' ') {
            // copy the word in reverse
            reverse_block(temp + last, string + last, i - last);
            temp[i] = ' ';
            last = i + 1;
        }
    }

    // copy the last word in reverse
    reverse_block(temp + last, string + last, len - last);

    // allocate an array, reverse the temp array into it and return it.
    return reverse_block(malloc(len + 1), temp, len);
}

int main(void) {
    const char *string = "This is a string";

    printf("%s\n", string);

    char *solution = reverse_words(string);
    printf("%s\n", solution);

    free(solution);

    return 0;
}
```

Now you can improve the code further by implementing a function that reverses a block in place.  With this, you no longer need a temporary buffer, you can work on the string copy directly and it simplifies the code.